# Rails can't dup NilClass error on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've got this in my controller:

```
@artists = Artist.where("artist LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").limit(500).paginate(params[:page])
```

And am getting the `can't dup NilClass` error.

Now, params[:term] and params[:page] are 2 different variables so why should the error appear? If I remove the second params variable, the error is gone.

It will still appear even if I do this:

```
page = params[:page]
```

Then below:

```
paginate(page)
```

I'd like to understand why this is happening and how to fix it, how to use 2 variables from params() in the same line without that error.

**Edit**

I've discovered that substituting an integer for params[:page] results in a slightly different error: `can't dup FixNum` so maybe the issue is not with params but something else. Still don't know how to solve it though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My mistake. I apologize profusely for this, but I was using paginate inappropriately. I wish I could delete this question, but there doesn't seem to be a way. The proper way to use it is:

```
paginate(:page => params[:page]
```

I guess that's what happens when you've been staring at code for too long :)

Maybe it will help others deal with Paginate. I really like it, but the errors could really be a little more descriptive.

For example, I will always get an unknown method error unless I do this:

```
<%= will_paginate @artists if @artists.respond_to? :total_pages %>
```

Comment: Definitely not something to delete, I was just making the same error!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for not removing this question. I was being equally neglegent and changing:
    paginate( params[ :page ] ) 
to 
    paginate( page: params[ :page ] )
 fixed it.

Comment: Glad it helped someone. I've since switched to Kaminari which has better support. Will_patinate seems to be dead in the water development wise.